# Adding WMS into the Google Maps or Mapbox

Tags: wms, mapbox

Is it possible for me to get the data from https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/web-services/ and add it as a layer in the maps so that whatever data I am getting from the server can be directly shown on my web page using Mapbox or Google API. I am new to this and like to integrate it in my project.

Comment: A WMS does give you data, just a (normally image) representation of it.  But you can use the service (in this case with an API key) in any application that supports the WMS specification to add layers.

Comment: Mapbox supports the use of WMS see documentation ~   https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/

Answer (score 2):

A working example below (tested). You just need to change mapbox token key and firms key with your own

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WMS Firms</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
    // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
    // ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
    // https://account.mapbox.com
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your_mapbox_token>';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
      zoom: 5,
      center: [-120.72347063061076, 36.35977058548748]
    });
  
    // Key obtained at https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/web-services/
    var firms_key = 'your_firm_key';
    // Layer name choosen among list in XML from url call in browser to
    // Use firms2.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov here instead of default firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov
    // due to current heavy traffic (when answering)
    // https://firms2.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/key/your_firm_key/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GETCAPABILITIES
    var layer_name = 'fires_modis_7';
  
    map.on('load', function () {
      map.addSource('wms-test-source', {
        'type': 'raster',
        // use the tiles option to specify a WMS tile source URL
        // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/
        'tiles': [
          `https://firms2.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/key/${firms_key}/?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=256&height=256&layers=${layer_name}`
        ],
        'tileSize': 256
      });
      map.addLayer({
          'id': 'wms-test-layer',
          'type': 'raster',
          'source': 'wms-test-source',
          'paint': {}
        },
        'aeroway-line'
      );
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Leaflet.js to create a map on a web page. With leaflet you can add data from any giver source (osm, google or even nasa).